# sharepoint 2007 wiki customization

Tags: 2007, web-part, wiki, sharepoint-foundation, content-editor-web-part

I have been asked to customize a SharePoint 2007 wiki site into a 'Wikipedia' like interface and functionality.

After a bit of goggling it turns out that wiki's are not that readily customizable!!

Any recommendations or resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As, this site is part of the SharePoint portal it is not possible for me to port to a different tool. And, my solution requires to add content types and webparts on the wiki pages.

Now, I am following the approach mentioned by Pavan to add a seperate wiki file for your customization http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pavankumar/archive/2009/02/25/custom-wiki-site-definition-with-custom-document-template-for-creating-wiki-pages.aspx.

If you have any other approach than this, please share :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Kwizcom](http://www.kwizcom.com/sharepoint-add-ons/sharepoint-wiki-plus/overview/)

If you want "wikipedia" than you'll probably need to look at [mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki).  There is no direct "integration path" but you could host along side SharePoint, on the same server(s) if you were so inclined.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, if users want Wikipedia like functionality, set up mediawiki like Jesus suggests.  They'll be disappointed with SharePoint wiki functionality if they're expecting a wikipedia experience.  If they want the look of wikipedia, you can always do some CSS styling to make it look similar.

Comment: As, this site is part of the SharePoint portal it is not possible for me to port to a different tool.